# How to connect docker container to vpn site to site

Tags: docker, network-programming, gcloud, vpn, openvpn

I have an application (nestjs) working into docker container into vm in google cloud, sending and receiving http requests to/from server of other company in other city/state (they use azure cloud).
But that other company created a vpn site to site, and now we need to make this container send and receive the http requests passing by that vpn site to site.
How can i setup and make just my container to connect like that, and not all my server host.

Create a vpn client into container?
I really need help about that. (tutorial, step by step, etc)
Thank you for attention.

I've tryied some tutorials about create a vpn, but i dont know if it is what i need, or a need only to be a client of the vpn of that other company.

Comment: Edit your question to include details on how the VPN is set up and the routing configuration. The key is to use the correct IP:PORT of the container running in Compute Engine.

Comment: Thank you.. But I really need to know how to create a vpn client in a docker container compatible with vpn of azure cloud.

Comment: Your question has been closed. I recommend reading why and then creating a new question with all the required details. Note: StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. Post a well-defined problem that can be answered with facts and or citations. Requesting a tutorial is off topic.